# Exploding tensor after using Dataset and .batch

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a numpy array of shape (100,4,30). This represents 100 samples of 4 samples of encodings of length 30. The 4 samples, per row, are related.

I want to get a TensorFlow dataset, batched, where related samples are in the same batch.

I'm trying to do:

first, use `np.vsplit` to get a list of length 100, where each element in the list is a list of the 4 related samples.

Now if I call `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(...).batch(1)` on this list of lists, I get a batch that contains a tensor of shape (4,1,30).

I want this batch to contain 4 tensors of shape (1,30).

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may have missunderstood you, but if you just leave out the "vsplit":

```
data = np.zeros((100, 4, 30))
data_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(data).batch(1)
for element in data_ds.take(1):
    print(element.shape)
```

you will get:

```
(1, 4, 30)
```

(so one batch contains all 4 related encodings).

If you really want the dimensions inside a batch to be 4 times (1, 30) you can do:

```
data = np.expand_dims(data, axis=2)
```

before dataset creation.

**EDIT:**

I think I just understood your question. You want every batch to have 4 elements and those are the related encodings? You can achieve this by:

```
data = np.swapaxes(data, 0, 1)
data = np.reshape(data, (100*4, -1))
data_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(data).batch(4)
```

Comment: Regarding your edit: no, I want each batch to contain more than four elements, but if x is in the batch, and y is related to x, then y should be in the batch.

Comment: Regarding your first solution: if I work with it, then I need TF to treat all these related samples as distinct "rows". That is, I want the input shape to be (batch size, 30). Where the batch size can be anything, but all related samples in the same batch.

Comment: This is exactly what I recommended; just replace ".batch(4)" with ".batch(number)" where number is {4, 8, 16...} depending on how many elements you want to have in your batch.

Comment: The input_shape of my solution is (batch_size, 30) and all related samples are in the same batch.

Comment: Ok, but this solution will work only if I make batch sizes multiples of four. In practice however this won't work because I don't expect to have four as a constant number of related encodings, per entry. Do you have an idea how to generalise this?

Comment: So what will be the shape of the input array?

Comment: I've accepted your answer, thanks! Also posted a question with the more difficult usecase: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72353638/tensorflow-batching-elements-with-same-key-in-same-batch